# change UTF-8&white-space URL to readable URL for web applications

Tags: php, url, utf-8

how to convert (in php)

> http://images.example.com//images/2014/12/14-12-27-114545کریم باقری در
>   تمرین تراکتور3 (300x200).jpg

to

> http://images.example.com//images/2014/12/14-12-27-114545%DA%A9%D8%B1%DB%8C%D9%85%20%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%82%D8%B1%DB%8C%20%D8%AF%D8%B1%20%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%B1%DB%8C%D9%86%20%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%A7%DA%A9%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%B13%20(300x200).jpg

Note: There are space in first URL.

I try this code but I failed:

```
function url_path_encode($url) {
    $path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
    if (strpos($path,'%') !== false) return $url; //avoid double encoding
    else {
        $encoded_path = array_map('urlencode', explode('/', $path));
        return str_replace($path, implode('/', $encoded_path), $url);
    }
```

> http://images.example.com//images/2014/12/14-12-27-114545%DA%A9%D8%B1%DB%8C%D9%85+%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%82%D8%B1%DB%8C+%D8%AF%D8%B1+%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%B1%DB%8C%D9%86+%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%A7%DA%A9%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%B13+%28300x200%29.jpg

online tools example: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Answer (score 0):

You try this?

(PHP 4, PHP 5)
urlencode — URL-encodes string

```
<?php
echo '<a href="mycgi?foo=', urlencode($userinput), '">';
?>
```

Comment: yes it encodes every chars: `http%3A%2F%2Fimages...2%2F14-12-27-114545%DA%A9%D...%B13+%28300x200%29.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

You look for [rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/it/function.rawurlencode.php)

```
function url_path_encode($url)
{
    $ret = '';
    if(false === $parts = parse_url($url)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (isset($parts['scheme'])) {
        $parts['scheme'] = $parts['scheme'] . '://';
    }

    if (isset($parts['path'])) {
        $parts['path'] = join('/', array_map('rawurlencode', explode('/', $parts['path'])));;
    }

    // ...

    return implode('', $parts);
}

echo url_path_encode('http://images.example.com//images/2014/12/14-12-27-114545کریم باقری در تمرین تراکتور3 (300x200).jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it via this functions:

```
function url_path_encode($url) {
    $unescaped = array(
        '%2D'=>'-','%5F'=>'_','%2E'=>'.','%21'=>'!', '%7E'=>'~',
        '%2A'=>'*', '%27'=>"'", '%28'=>'(', '%29'=>')'
    );
    $reserved = array(
        '%3B'=>';','%2C'=>',','%2F'=>'/','%3F'=>'?','%3A'=>':',
        '%40'=>'@','%26'=>'&','%3D'=>'=','%2B'=>'+','%24'=>'$'
    );
    $score = array(
        '%23'=>'#'
    );
    return strtr(rawurlencode($url), array_merge($reserved,$unescaped,$score)); 
}
```